# How to distribute by ID using Block Pattern?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

As I started to learn bloc pattern, I wanted to create a small app with this pattern. So now I am trying to understand what I should do if I want to each users from the first list can have their own todo's by id.

I create this function due to separate logic from the UI:

```
void findByID(List<Users> users){
    if(users == null) return;
    final _findById = users.where((element) => element.id == element.id).toList();
 }
```

Now I don't understand how to put this fucntion to UI. Now I have two loaded lists fron API which just shows the list of users and the list of todo without distribution by user's id.

The whole class with logis is like so:

```
class ApisBloc{
  final _repos = Repositary();
  final _usersFetcher = PublishSubject<List<Users>>();
  final _todoUsers = PublishSubject<List<UsersToDos>>();

  Stream<List<Users>> get allUsers => _usersFetcher.stream;
  Stream<List<UsersToDos>> get allTodos => _todoUsers.stream;

  fetchUsers() async{
    List<Users> usersModels = await _repos.fetchUsers();
    _usersFetcher.sink.add(usersModels);
  }

  fetchTodos() async{
    List<UsersToDos> todo = await _repos.fetchTodosUsers();
    _todoUsers.sink.add(todo);
  }

  dispose(){
    _usersFetcher.close();
    _todoUsers.close();
  }

 void findByID(List<Users> users){
    if(users == null) return;
    final _findById = users.where((element) => element.id == element.id).toList();
 }

}
final bloc = ApisBloc();
```

I think I should put function `findByID` in the Navigation and make it async?

Comment: I would suggest you use the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc package to implement this pattern, trying to reinvent the wheel leads to a lot of weird wheels that don't work. You seem to have all users and all todo's as streams. Maybe you want to have a stream for TODOs filtered users? Or just one user as a stream? It's a little hard to tell, we don't know what your program is supposed to do with this information.

Comment: @nvoigt yes, I want to filter all todo's according to users's ids. Now I have two streams with just the whole users's list and the whole todo's list without filtering. I use this flutter_bloc which you mentioned.

Comment: Create a third stream then?

Comment: @nvoigt as I understood from docs and articles if I want to do some logic (it dosen't matter if it is filtering, sorting or any other kind where I manipulate data from the API) I should create the new streams and put it in the UI. I think your suggestion can be right, I'll try it